# Jeresy List of Object[] response

Tags: json, rest, jersey, jersey-client

There is a way to return POJO conatins List of array of objects from jersey web service as a response?

If this is my POJO:

```
@xmlRootElement
Public class Test implements Serializable {

    private List<Object[]> entities;

    public List<Object[]> getEntities() {
        return entities;
    }

    public void setEntities(List<Object[]> entities){
         this.entities = entities;
    }

}
```

It seems that jersey is able to marshall the response but unable to unmarshall it back at the client side.

This is the Exception Im getting at the client side:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.SAX2DOM.startElement(SAX2DOM.java:200) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler.closeStartTag(ToXMLSAXHandler.java:204) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler.characters(ToXMLSAXHandler.java:524) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerHandlerImpl.characters(TransformerHandlerImpl.java:168) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.DomLoader.text(DomLoader.java:143) ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:2.2.3]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.text(UnmarshallingContext.java:499) ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:2.2.3]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.text(InterningXmlVisitor.java:93) ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:2.2.3]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.processText(StAXStreamConnector.java:339) ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:2.2.3]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleEndElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:217) ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:2.2.3]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:186) ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:2.2.3]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:366) ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:2.2.3]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:345) ~[jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:2.2.3]
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.BaseJSONUnmarshaller.unmarshalJAXBElementFromJSON(BaseJSONUnmarshaller.java:108) ~[jersey-json-1.12.jar:1.12]
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.BaseJSONUnmarshaller.unmarshalFromJSON(BaseJSONUnmarshaller.java:97) ~[jersey-json-1.12.jar:1.12]
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider.readFrom(JSONRootElementProvider.java:129) ~[jersey-json-1.12.jar:1.12]
at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.readFrom(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:111) ~[jersey-core-1.12.jar:1.12]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:554) ~[jersey-client-1.12.jar:1.12]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:506) ~[jersey-client-1.12.jar:1.12]
at com.audiocodes.ms.control.strategy.cms.CMSStrategy.getSystemInfo(CMSStrategy.java:172) ~[bin/:na]
at com.audiocodes.ms.control.actors.SystemActor.getSystemInfo(SystemActor.java:69) [bin/:na]
at com.audiocodes.ms.control.actors.SystemActor.onReceive(SystemActor.java:33) [bin/:na]
at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:159) [akka-actor_2.10-2.1.2.jar:na]
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:425) [akka-actor_2.10-2.1.2.jar:na]
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:386) [akka-actor_2.10-2.1.2.jar:na]
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:230) [akka-actor_2.10-2.1.2.jar:na]
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:212) [akka-actor_2.10-2.1.2.jar:na]
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:506) [akka-actor_2.10-2.1.2.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:262) [scala-library-2.10.1.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975) [scala-library-2.10.1.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478) [scala-library-2.10.1.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104) [scala-library-2.10.1.jar:na]
```

Im using jersey 1.12.

Does anyone know where is my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: Edited and presented at the main question.